# How to get a UA-******** tag for a Firebase based app

Tags: react-native, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I've developed a React-Native app using Firebase and integrated it to Google Analytics.
In the app's Google Analytics account there is a number in the format of, something like 233242342 and no a UA-23423423-1.

I couldn't find/understand how to get a UA tag. I wish to add custom events etc'

Answer (score 1):

You won't get a UA for Firebase. The number you have is a "stream id" that you'll feed into GA4, not UA.

Comment: how do I use google analytics events etc' with a UA number? All libraries require it in initialization.

Comment: @AYBABTU your using the wrong libray only libraies designed for UA require it, you need to use a library designed for GA4